# Azure Data Factory Mapping Data Flow to CSV sink results in zero-byte files

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I'm sharpening up my Azure Data Factory chops, comparing Copy Activity performance vs Mapping Data Flows writing to a single CSV file in Azure Blob Storage.

When I write to a Single CSV through an Azure Blob Storage Linked Service (azureBlobLinkedService) through a Dataset (azureBlobSingleCSVFileNameDataset), using a Copy Activity get the output in the blob storage container that I expect.  For example, an output file of MyData.csv in the container MyContainer under the folder /output/csv/singleFiles.

When I write to a Single CSV through the same Blob Storage Linked Service, but through a different DataSet (azureBlobSingleCSVNoFileNameDataset), using a Mapping Data Flow I get the following:

- MyContainer/output/csv/singleFiles (zero length file)
- MyContainer/output/csv/singleFiles/MyData.csv (contains the data that I expect)

I don't understand why I'm getting the zero length files produced when using a Mapping Data Flow.

Here are my source files:

linkedService/azureBlobLinkedService

```
{
    "name": "azureBlobLinkedService",
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/linkedservices",
    "properties": {
        "type": "AzureBlobStorage",
        "parameters": {
            "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": {
                "type": "AzureKeyVaultSecret",
                "store": {
                    "referenceName": "AzureKeyVaultLinkedService",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "secretName": "@{linkedService().azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName}"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

dataset/azureBlobSingleCSVFileNameDataset

```
{
    "name": "azureBlobSingleCSVFileNameDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "azureBlobLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
            "parameters": {
                "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "azureBlobSingleCSVFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "fileName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobSingleCSVFileName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "container": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

pipeline/Azure SQL Table to Blob Single CSV Copy Pipeline (this produces expected results)

```
{
    "name": "Azure SQL Table to Blob Single CSV Copy Pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy Azure SQL Table to Blob Single CSV",
                "type": "Copy",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                        "queryTimeout": "02:00:00"
                    },
                    "sink": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSink",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobStorageWriteSettings"
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextWriteSettings",
                            "quoteAllText": true,
                            "fileExtension": ".csv"
                        }
                    },
                    "enableStaging": false
                },
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "azureSqlDatabaseTableDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "azureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "azureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "azureSqlDatabaseTableTableName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableTableName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "referenceName": "azureBlobSingleCSVFileNameDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobConnectionStringSecretName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "azureBlobSingleCSVFileName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFileName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVContainerName",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableTableName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

dataset/azureBlobSingleCSVNoFileNameDataset: (no filename in dataset required by mapping data flow, set in the mapping data flow)

```
{
    "name": "azureBlobSingleCSVNoFileNameDataset",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "azureBlobLinkedService",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference",
            "parameters": {
                "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        "parameters": {
            "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobStorageLocation",
                "folderPath": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "container": {
                    "value": "@dataset().azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            },
            "columnDelimiter": ",",
            "escapeChar": "\\",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": "\""
        },
        "schema": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/datasets"
}
```

dataflow/azureSqlDatabaseTableToAzureBlobSingleCSVDataFlow

```
{
    "name": "azureSqlDatabaseTableToAzureBlobSingleCSVDataFlow",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "azureSqlDatabaseTableDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "readFromAzureSqlDatabase"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "azureBlobSingleCSVNoFileNameDataset",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "writeToAzureBlobSingleCSV"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [
                {
                    "name": "enrichWithRuntimeMetadata"
                }
            ],
            "script": "\nparameters{\n\tsourceConnectionSecretName as string,\n\tsinkConnectionStringSecretName as string,\n\tsourceObjectName as string,\n\tsinkObjectName as string,\n\tdataFactoryName as string,\n\tdataFactoryPipelineName as string,\n\tdataFactoryPipelineRunId as string,\n\tsinkFileNameNoPath as string\n}\nsource(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tisolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',\n\tformat: 'table') ~> readFromAzureSqlDatabase\nreadFromAzureSqlDatabase derive({__sourceConnectionStringSecretName} = $sourceConnectionSecretName,\n\t\t{__sinkConnectionStringSecretName} = $sinkConnectionStringSecretName,\n\t\t{__sourceObjectName} = $sourceObjectName,\n\t\t{__sinkObjectName} = $sinkObjectName,\n\t\t{__dataFactoryName} = $dataFactoryName,\n\t\t{__dataFactoryPipelineName} = $dataFactoryPipelineName,\n\t\t{__dataFactoryPipelineRunId} = $dataFactoryPipelineRunId) ~> enrichWithRuntimeMetadata\nenrichWithRuntimeMetadata sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,\n\tvalidateSchema: false,\n\tpartitionFileNames:[($sinkFileNameNoPath)],\n\tpartitionBy('hash', 1),\n\tquoteAll: true) ~> writeToAzureBlobSingleCSV"
        }
    }
}
```

pipeline/Azure SQL Table to Blob Single CSV Data Flow Pipeline (this produces the expected results, plus zero-byte file at folder paths.)

```
{
    "name": "Azure SQL Table to Blob Single CSV Data Flow Pipeline",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Copy Sql Database Table To Blob Single CSV Data Flow",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "azureSqlDatabaseTableToAzureBlobSingleCSVDataFlow",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "sourceConnectionSecretName": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "sinkConnectionStringSecretName": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobConnectionStringSecretName}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "sourceObjectName": {
                                "value": "'@{concat('[', pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName, '].[', pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableTableName, ']')}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "sinkObjectName": {
                                "value": "'@{concat(pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVContainerName, '/', pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath, '/', \npipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFileName)}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "dataFactoryName": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().DataFactory}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "dataFactoryPipelineName": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().Pipeline}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "dataFactoryPipelineRunId": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().RunId}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            },
                            "sinkFileNameNoPath": {
                                "value": "'@{pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFileName}'",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        },
                        "datasetParameters": {
                            "readFromAzureSqlDatabase": {
                                "azureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "azureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "azureSqlDatabaseTableTableName": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableTableName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            },
                            "writeToAzureBlobSingleCSV": {
                                "azureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobConnectionStringSecretName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "azureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "azureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                                    "value": "@pipeline().parameters.sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVContainerName",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableSchemaName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sourceAzureSqlDatabaseTableTableName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobConnectionStringSecretName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVContainerName": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFolderPath": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "sinkAzureBlobSingleCSVFileName": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The reason to get 0 lengths (bytes) files means that while your pipeline may have run with success, it did not return or produce any output.

One of the better techniques is to preview the output of every stage to be sure that each stage there is an expected output.

Comment: (this produces the expected results, plus zero-byte file at folder paths.)  I get the output I expect PLUS zero-byte files at each folder point.When I write to a Single CSV through the same Blob Storage Linked Service, but through a different DataSet (azureBlobSingleCSVNoFileNameDataset), using a Mapping Data Flow I get the following:

MyContainer/output/csv/singleFiles (zero length file)
MyContainer/output/csv/singleFiles/MyData.csv (contains the data that I expect)
I don't understand why I'm getting the zero length files produced when using a Mapping Data Flow.

Comment: any update on this issue? I am experiencing the same.